# Azure devops contributors have no access to GIT repository feature

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have users who are external guests in the Azure AD used for Azure Devops.  None of the users see the Repository feature at all in the menu, and if I try to provide direct links to a repository they get a 403 denied.

They are all in the contributors group  which has  contributor permission to the repository.

I even tried make them collection administrators.  Any steps recommended resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like they don't have the right Access Level to access the Repo feature, which is about giving the right license to their accounts - see [Access levels in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#supported-access-levels).

If they are **Stakeholders** only, they won't even see the icon. You would require to have them being assigned a **Basic** license. You can find the way to change Access Level (license) in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).